# Getting a weird error with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This is very difficult to explain, so I took pictures. The first is the error I'm getting, the second is that section of code. Can anyone help me determine what is wrong? I can provide more information if needed.

http://tinypic.com/r/14dlu2v/5

http://tinypic.com/r/2057grb/5

EDIT: Fixed!

Comment: `echo` the query and run it directly in the DB and see what you're getting. Probably syntax error.

Comment: If you cannot explain it, how do you think we can understand it? Why don't you show the error message a plain text in your question? Copy & Paste was invented also for that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you may want to check whether you got a return set. See the documentation below, look at example two.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php

Comment: I'm sorry, I really know absolutely nothing about SQL. I appreciate the answer, but I'm not sure how to go about figuring this out.

Comment: After you call mysqli->query check that the returned value is really an object and that you have a result set.